# Find index in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, indexing

If I know the key name, how can I find the list index when data is structured like this?

```
foo = [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}]
```

For example, given the string `'key2'`, what is its index in the list above?

My current code:

```
for i in xrange(len(foo)):
    if foo[i].keys()[0] == 'key1':
        print i
```

I'm curious however if there is some slick technique that does not require an explicit loop.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: `foo.keys().index('key1')`

Comment: @Josh `foo` is a list.

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction now why on earth would he do that? I apologize, I didn't realize we weren't dealing with a dictionary.

Comment: @Josh List of dicts is pretty common, especially when dealing with JSON data.

Comment: I've come up with this... for i in xrange(len(foo)): if foo[i].keys()[0] == 'key1': print i.  It works.  I'm curious if there is some slick technique that does not require an explicit loop.

Comment: @bholben Always post your attempt with the question. **No**, here you cannot prevent a for-loop here, though you can add a `break` statement to stop the loop as soon as a match is found. But, iCodez's approach is what I'd use.

Comment: @bholben - I moved your comment into your question so that it is more visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
>>> foo = [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3'}]
>>> next((i for i,d in enumerate(foo) if 'key1' in d), None)
0
>>> next((i for i,d in enumerate(foo) if 'key2' in d), None)
1
>>> next((i for i,d in enumerate(foo) if 'key3' in d), None)
2
>>> next((i for i,d in enumerate(foo) if 'key4' in d), None)
>>>
```

Note that you can also replace `None` with any default value:

```
>>> next((i for i,d in enumerate(foo) if 'key4' in d), 'not found')
'not found'
>>>
```

---

Also, I would like to mention that doing:

```
if foo[i].keys()[0] == 'key1':
```

will not always work if the dictionaries have more than one item.  This is because a dictionary's keys are naturally unordered:

```
>>> d = {'abc':1, 'xyz':2}
>>> d.keys()
['xyz', 'abc']
>>>
```

In addition, there is no need to call the `keys` method of a dictionary to search its keys because you have the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
>>> 'abc' in d
True
>>> 'def' in d
False
>>>
```

This solution is also a lot more efficient because it avoids creating an unnecessary list.

Comment: I think you should now also explain what's wrong with using `if foo[i].keys()[0] == 'key1'`. :)

Comment: Generators are new to me.  This looks like a great opportunity for me to embrace them.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction - Better? :)